# Netbeans Module Development out of memory

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, out-of-memory

I am creating a module in netbeans to help with a project i am working on however when I run the module in the developmental IDE i get an out of memory exception while loading an asset. This procedure seems to work fine in the base netbeans environment but when  i make the same calls during module development i get the error. After attempting to load the asset in several differnt ways i tried appending the following to project.properties and then to Netbeans Platform config(platform.properties)

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-Xms384m -J-Xmx1024m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=96m -J-Xverify:none"
```

and also tried

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xverify:none -J-Xmx1024m -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true"
```

I have also tried

```
test.run.args=-ea -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Have never created a NB module but I know that in java app and webapp one can set xmx and xms options from project properties. DO you see that option when you right click on your project name and go to properties.

Comment: No but their is a field in the Run Section of a typical non modular project called VM Options

Comment: Yes that's where you should be giving your VM options like xmx xms and permgen

Comment: i meant it only shows up in a normal project not a module project but thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in this issue for a while. Adding this line into project.properties has solved the problem:
`run.args.extra=-J-Xms128m -J-Xmx512m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

While it improved the heap memory size, apparently the problem was gone because of the increased non-heap memory size (J-XX:MaxPermSize=512m).

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If the problem occurs when you install your module in the development IDE, you can configure the maximum heap size and perm size in `<netbeans-install-dir>/etc/netbeans.conf` by appending your `-J-Xmx` and `-J-XX:MaxPermSize` parameters to the netbeans_default_options variable. You should also append `-J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled`, as noted in the docs (see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqGCPauses).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar memory problem on my Linux Debian.

Only Works on linux / possibly UNIX OS's???

Here is how to fix it:

1. run a terminal
2. log in as root
3. type `crontab -e`
4. scroll to the bottom or the file and type `* * * * * sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

This magic line cleared all unused ram every minute. It removed the unused memory NetBeans was producing (including any other memory-consuming programs).

plz tell me if this works.

Answer (score 0):

solution to Out of memory exception in netbeans is![.....][1]

I have tried by setting project properties.

right click on **project** --> select **Properties**-->**General Settings**-->VM Options

Add below parameters **-Xms256m -Xmx512m**